# Qt 5.3.2: Screen tearing after running a Quick 2.0 app by eglfs on TI AM335x

Tags: qt, qt5.3

We got a screen tearing after 10 mins running Qt5 clocks example by eglfs. The behavior before 10 mins looks good, but after that below warning message keep showing up:

```
Could not wait for vsync.
```

We saw this message because we do:

```
export QT_QPA_EGLFS_FORCEVSYNC=1
```

The QSurfaceFormat info is:

```
Created context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior 2, swapInterval 1, profile  0) with config:
EGL_BUFFER_SIZE: 16
EGL_ALPHA_SIZE: 0
EGL_BLUE_SIZE: 5
EGL_GREEN_SIZE: 6
EGL_RED_SIZE: 5
EGL_DEPTH_SIZE: 24
EGL_STENCIL_SIZE: 8
EGL_CONFIG_CAVEAT: 12344
EGL_CONFIG_ID: 8
EGL_LEVEL: 0
EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_HEIGHT: 2048
EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_PIXELS: 4194304
EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_WIDTH: 2048
EGL_NATIVE_RENDERABLE: 0
EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID: 0
EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_TYPE: 0
EGL_SAMPLES: 0
EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS: 0
EGL_SURFACE_TYPE: 7
EGL_TRANSPARENT_TYPE: 12344
EGL_TRANSPARENT_BLUE_VALUE: 0
EGL_TRANSPARENT_GREEN_VALUE: 0
EGL_TRANSPARENT_RED_VALUE: 0
EGL_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_RGB: 0
EGL_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_RGBA: 0
EGL_MIN_SWAP_INTERVAL: 1
EGL_MAX_SWAP_INTERVAL: 1
```

By checking Qt's source code, we know setting QT_QPA_EGLFS_FORCEVSYNC to 1 will let Qt do the ioctl for FBIO_WAITFORVSYNC. The ioctl returns success until 10 mins after running the app.

Does anybody has any hints or suggestion on how to eliminate the tearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstand the meaning of "tearing". Actually my situation is just because the framebuffer console blanking mentioned in the [this link](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AM335x_LCD_Controller_Driver's_Guide).

The solution is to turn off the blanking by kernel bootargs "consoleblank=0".